# Is it possible that key bindings in vim in tmux get some delay after some usage?

Tags: vim, key-bindings, tmux

I use vim inside tmux. Some key bindings such as `<Leader>k` get some delay after using vim a while. When I restart vim, there is no delay for some time.

I couldn't find the exact cause of this problem, therefore I just want to check if there is anything that might help me to find out what causes this problem.

I checked `verbose map <Leader>k`, there is no other mapping. The problem occurs only inside tmux. I have a standalone MacVim window which is always open and it doesn't have any delay at all.

Comment: I had a problem with key delays a time ago. And it worked for me setting `ttimeoutlen`, in vim, to a low number (i.e. `set ttimeoutlen=50`).